# is any methods for refreshing data in table in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refresh

As I'm trying to refresh the page by using window.location.reload() method the page is reloading but it is redirecting from current page to home page.I have searched more number of methods like setInterval() but when we add,delete and edit the record after clicking the submit button the record in the table is not visible.so as i'm new to this react js,anyone please help me to overcome from this issue

Comment: You shouldn't think of it this way. You rather need to figure out in response to which event (user interactions or [server-sent event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)) your app state (which has to include table data) has to be updated, so that React may re-render according to the most recent values. In any case, reloading the page doesn't look like a good option (in the context of SPA) and without relevant code samples and more specific problem statement, your question is way too broad.

Comment: But the table is not refreshing automatically..is that need to re-render??

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach maybe must be store the data of your table like a state.

If you're using hooks:

```
const [dataTable, setDataTable] = useState(null)
```

And after you add, edit or delete a record you should update your dataTable state with the new dataTable.

```
onDataTableChange = (data) => {
setDataTable(data) }
```

This going to update your state and re-render with the new data.